# Math interface vs cMath in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, cmath

The interface on my build system MacOS 10.6.3 for the POSIX math library is math.h, however on my target system the name of the interface file is cmath.h.  At school we use cmath and I would like to be sure my project compiles when it is handed in, how is this achieved.  The servers and workstations at school are x86 running Windows XP.  The GCC is available on both platforms.

Comment: What is your "target system". What compiler, what operating system ?? Ask your teacher the differences between `cmath.h` and `math.h`? Is it `<cmath>` or `<cmath.h>`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean macos is my host system and windows XP is my target system.  And if my prof knew the answer, then I wouldn't have to ask here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the C++ standard, the math library functions are defined in two headers:

```
<cmath>
```

contains them in the namespace `std` (e.g. `std::sin`), while

```
<math.h>
```

contains them in the global namespace (so just `sin`).

There are further differences between the two: while `<math.h>` contains all the C math functions with distinct names for distinct types, such as

```
double sin(double);
float sinf(float);
long double sinl(long double);
```

etc., `<cmath>` contains overloaded functions such as

```
namespace std {
    double sin(double);
    float sin(float);
    long double sin(long double);
}
```

etc. (C++ libraries might additionally export `sinf` from `<cmath>`, but you can't rely on this in a portable program.)

Finally, the `fabs`, `fabsf` and `fabsl` functions from the C standard library have become overloads of `std::abs` in `<cmath>`.

Though both headers are in the standard, you should really prefer `<cmath>`, as `<math.h>` is only there for backward compatibility with pre-standard C++ and C.

There's no such thing as `<cmath.h>` in standard C++.

Comment: OK. Removed my answer rather than edit it, as you've covered the important bits here. I think a mention of the use of the <cfoo> naming style for other standard libraries is worthwhile, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: @HarperShelby: put that in, near the end. I hope the OP reads that far, cause this is quite a list ;)

Comment: The goal is to get good information out there - you can lead a horse to water and all that.

Comment: Ok so in C++ header file names should be specified without a .h, and this is in theory why I can't link against cmath, but there is no manpage on cmath (at least not on my system), so I don't know if it is properly installed and my laptop just died, so  I'll check back later and see if it is still an issue.

Comment: @awiebe: I've never seen a system that has manpages on the C++ library. Manpages tend to cover the C library only.

Comment: On macos the C++ standard libraries are not located where I would expect them to be, this may be an error in my system configuration(my $PATH variable is missing a path), because running the gcc from the command line causes error, however creating an xcode project using commandline tool -> c++ -> stdc++ adds the appropriate paths to the target so that fixed it.