# Including standard header files. string.h or cstring? or both?

Tags: c++, c, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between string.h and cstring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380805/difference-between-string-h-and-cstring)

What is better programming practice in C++ when including the standard header files with respect to

including `cmath` in place of `math.h` or vice-versa?

including `cstring` in place of `string.h` or vice-versa?

and for other `<c*>` and `<*.h>` header files which apparently seem to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @Jefromi: not exactly a dupe; this question also pertains to `<cmath>`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`<cstring>` is newer; `<string.h>` is really there for backwards compatibility (and for C, of course). The difference is that `<cstring>` puts the string functions in the `std` namespace, while `<string.h>` puts them in the global namespace.

In addition, `<cstring>` changes the types of certain functions to promote type-safety. E.g., the C declaration

```
char *strchr(char const *, int);
```

is replaced by the overloads (in the `std` namespace)

```
char       *strchr(char       *, int);
char const *strchr(char const *, int);
```

In the case of `<cmath>` there are [further differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734230/math-interface-vs-cmath-in-c/8734292#8734292) with `<math.h>` which make `<cmath>` more idiomatic and less C-like.

Prefer `<cstring>` for new code and use the `std::` prefix on the functions.