# Random not declared in scope

Tags: c++, include

I am getting the error:

> tester.cpp|20|error: 'rand' was not declared in this scope|

Did I miss to include something here?

```
void tester::volumeset(bool A_B, int i, int v)
{
    if (A_B == true)
    {
        A_volumn[i] = rand(v+1);
    }else{
        B_volumn[i] = rand(v+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the correct `#include` file or even declared the function?

Comment: Yea i have this

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>

Comment: I saw this on c++ forums unless its not an actualfunction in c++?

Comment: I've never seen that C++ function. C has a `rand()` function

Comment: Just so you know, `#include`ing `<stdlib.h>` and `<cstdlib>` are the same thing. For system headers (wrapped in `<>`) that came from C, you can either use their original name with a `.h`, as in `<stdlib.h>` or use the newer C++ name which drops the `.h` and adds a `c` at the beginning: `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: Indirectly related, not a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float/686373

Comment: @Ari: they're not the same. `<cstdlib>` puts standard C functions in the `std` namespace and may add a bunch of overloads (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8734292/166749).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`random` is not a standard C++ function; it's a [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/random.html) function, so it's not available on Windows. Use [`rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random) instead, or better, the new [C++11 randomness library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: How do you access the POSIX `random` function? I've never heard of it before.

Comment: @soniccool: `rand()` returns a random number in the range `[0, RAND_MAX)`, so `rand() % k` will give (non-uniformly distributed) random number in the range `[0, k)`.

Comment: How would i rewrite this `random(v+1);`` in c++?

Answer (score 8):

`rand` is part of `cstdlib`, try including `cstdlib` in your code.

`#include <cstdlib>`

or

`#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `rand()`, not `random()`. You can see some examples of how to use it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Answer (score 0):

when i compile my code with Code::Blocks i don't need to `#include <cstdlib>`, with DevC++ i simply added `#include <cstdlib>` and it works for me.

Comment: What's the difference from [Rishabh Agrahari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393947/5376789)?

Answer (score -3):

`enter code here`only including #include  or #include  may not work it is better to use for instance I get a challenge when I use rand(100) but instead of this when I use rand()%100 it works well. try and enjoy it.

```
for(i=0;i<cust;i++)
{

  rsr[i]=rand(100);
 }

it works when I change it to 
 for(i=0;i<cust;i++)
 {

  rsr[i]=rand()%100;
  }
```

if you want to make it 1-100 use below but 0-99 use the above

```
for(i=0;i<cust;i++)
 {

  rsr[i]=rand()%(100+1);
  }

for(i=0;i<cust;i++)
 {

  rsr[i]=rand()%100+1;
  }
```