# Why use <cheader> instead of <header.h>?

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files

I've always thought that if you do `#include <cheader>` (where `header` is some standard c++ header like stdio/stdlib/string), it is the same that `#include <header.h>`, but wrapped into the `std` namespace. How does that code snippet compiles then (g++ 4.7.3)?

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
    malloc(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Why should one include `<cstdio>` then (instead of `<stdio.h>`) if standard C functions will be in the global namespace anyway?

And the second question is — what should I do to get some of these functions out of the global namespace (while using c++ headers at the same time)? For instance, I don't want `malloc` to be in the global namespace since I have a home assignment : to write my own memory allocator (in particular, `malloc` and `free` functions) which I will compile into dynamic library and plug into any program using `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: Because, unfortunately, implementations are *allowed* to have the names outside of the `std::` namespace, as well as *required* to have them inside it.

Comment: @juanchopanza but what's the point of using namespace `std` if we allow standard headers to clutter up the global namespace?

Comment: @karlicoss exactly! That is why I consider it "unfortunate". It only applies to names that come from the standard C library. All standard C++ functions and types are exclusively in the `std::` namespace.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/8734230/166749

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does that code snippet compiles then (g++ 4.7.3)?

Because 17.6.1.2/4 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> [...] It is
>   unspecified whether these names are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected
>   into namespace `std` by explicit *using-declarations* (7.3.3).

Therefore, implementations are allowed to define those entities in the global namespace.

> Why should one include  then (instead of ) if standard C functions will be in the global namespace anyway?

First of all, as a matter of good style. Including `<stdio.h>` gives you the *certainty* that all the entities are defined in the global namespace, while including `<cstdio>` gives you the certainty that those entities are where you want (in the `std` namespace), with the *possible* (but not certain) unwanted drawback that those names may appear in the global namespace too.

> what should I do to get some of these functions out of the global namespace (while using c++ headers at the same time)?

Unfortunately, you cannot get an entity out of the namespace it lives in. But what you *can* do (apart from cursing at your implementation) is to avoid using Standard C functions altogether, and prefer using functions from the C++ Standard Library. Those are guaranteed to live in the `std` namespace.

So for instance, if you *have to* perform low-level memory management, use the `new` operator instead of `malloc`. Also, mind the emphasis on "*have to*": most of the time, you should use RAII wrappers such as smart pointers or standard containers to avoid having to cope with low-level memory management, `new`, and `delete` at all.

Comment: Yeah, I would certainly use the `new` operator, RAII and other stuff if I had to write some c++ application. However, I have to write the memory allocator, which other programs (binaries, like `gcc` or `vim` or whatever) will use. I can use only very low-level memory abstractions like `mmap` system call in that assignment.

Comment: @karlicoss: I'm not sure I understand why you cannot use the `new` operator; especially I'm not sure I understand this part: "* I have to write the memory allocator, which other programs (binaries, like gcc or vim or whatever) will use*". But well, I don't need to understand, as long as you know what you're doing ;) Anyway the moral of the story is: you can't take an entity out of the namespace it's declared in, but you *should* hope that your implementation will declare them in the `std` namespace. If it doesn't... well, at least you did your part an included the right headers.

Comment: because `new` and `delete` are still high level memory abstractions for this home assignment. Well, I have to implement a memory management library (with `malloc`, `free`, `calloc`, etc.), basically, I have to implement [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(programming)) myself. Then I'll run something like `LD_PRELOAD=myallocator.so some_program` and that program will use my memory allocator instead of the one provided by `g++`.